# RSS 2.0 feed - set update limit for Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, rss, outlook, outlook-2007

I am generating an RSS 2.0 feed using **System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed** for Outlook 2007 SP2 clients, and I would like to know if it is possible to set the update limit for the feed in order to be recognized by Outlook client.

Comment: would you mind sharing a little more information about what this does? I'm desperate to find more info about automating RSS / Outlook via VBA, are you using VSTO, is that what I'm not understanding?

Comment: No, I was interested in setting the RSS feed properties so that Outlook, when adding the RSS feed, will use the specified properties. Outlook was never harmed in any way during this process (with VSTO or VBA or something else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [syndication extension](http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/) module:

```
feed.AttributeExtensions.Add(new XmlQualifiedName("sy", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"), "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/");
feed.ElementExtensions.Add("updatePeriod", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/", "daily");
feed.ElementExtensions.Add("updateFrequency", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/", 6);
feed.ElementExtensions.Add("updateBase", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/", DateTime.UtcNow);
```